# Rename files with counter over subdirectories

Tags: bash, rename, filenames

I have a parent directory with a number of directories in it. Within those I, again, have multiple subdirectories, they contain many images:

```
Parent
|
├──dirA
|       ├──sub_A1
|       |     ├──00000001.jpg 
|       |     ├──00000002.jpg 
|       |     ├──00000003.jpg
|       |
|       ├──sub_A2
|             ├──00000001.jpg 
|             ├──00000002.jpg 
|             ├──00000003.jpg
|    
├──dirB
       ├──sub_B1
       |     ├──00000001.jpg 
       |     ├──00000002.jpg 
       |     ├──00000003.jpg
       |
       ├──sub_B2
             ├──00000001.jpg 
             ├──00000002.jpg 
             ├──00000003.jpg
```

I would like to rename all the images in an incremental manner i.e. 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc. However, I don't want the counter to reset for the subdirectories.

So this would be the output:

```
Parent
|   
├──dirA
|       ├──sub_A1
|       |     ├──1.jpg 
|       |     ├──2.jpg 
|       |     ├──3.jpg
|       |
|       ├──sub_A2
|             ├──4.jpg 
|             ├──5.jpg 
|             ├──6.jpg
|    
├──dirB
       ├──sub_B1
       |     ├──7.jpg 
       |     ├──8.jpg 
       |     ├──9.jpg
       |
       ├──sub_B2
             ├──10.jpg 
             ├──11.jpg 
             ├──12.jpg
```

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37146/162057) almost seems to have the solution, but the counter does not reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
find DirPath -type f -name "*.*"|\
  for (( n=1;; ++n ));\
    do l="`line`"||break; mv "$l" "${l%/*}/$n.${l##*.}"; done
```

The `-name` clause is because the file name splitting fails if there is no dot in it, though you may prefer `-iname "*.jpg"`. The `do` clause could be elaborated to handle extensionless file names.

Note that `line` returns an error at end of file, so `||break` terminates the loop.

I recommend adding `echo` before `mv` to make sure that the command works as expected: you could save this output as a reference to the changes made.

If you need to sort the directories and files before assigning the numbers, which seems a sensible thing to do, add a sort filter, specifying `/` as a field separator:

```
find DirPath -type f -name "*.*"|sort -t /|\
  for (( n=1;; ++n ));\
    do l="`line`"||break; mv "$l" "${l%/*}/$n.${l##*.}"; done
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Can I ask, how do I make sure the subdirectories get processed in alphabetical order? It seems now, the folders get processed in a random order?

Comment: Yes, `find` doesn't have a sort option, but you can add a sort filter between the `find` command and the `for` loop: `find ... |sort -t /|for ...`. This will sort both the directories and the files by using `/` as a field separator.

Comment: I've added it to my answer, as it seems a sensible thing to want.

Comment: A final note: if you have files and subdirectories in the same directory, then this sort may intersperse the files in the subdirectories. In your illustration the file names are numeric, and will precede any alphabetic subdirectory names, which is probably a reasonable order, but the sort filter would need to be a lot more complex to achieve this with mixed alphanumeric file and directory names.

Comment: Ah yes I see, thanks for this remark. In my data, the file names are all purely numerical, and the subdirectories names are all alphabetical. I can't upvote your answer, sorry about that!